# Pagination not changing when clicking on checkbox

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a filter function. Filtering is working as expected but pagination is not updating. When I click on "Mobile Phone" checkbox it shows one record in the first page, two records in second page and so on..
Also, page count is not updating according to the search result.

How to solve this?

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<body ng-app="ngTest" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-cloak >

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeType('Tablet')"  >Tablet
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeType('Mobile Phone')"  >Mobile Phone

        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeDistrict('Galle')"  >Galle
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeDistrict('Kandy')"  >Kandy



    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <h4>{{ads.length}} total</h4>

        <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="ad in filteredAds | filter:searchFilter | filter:typeFilter | filter:districtFilter"   style="border:1px solid #d84530; margin-bottom:20px;">

            <p >Post Id: {{ad.post_id}}<br/>
                User Id: {{ad.user_id}}<br/>
                District: {{ad.district}}<br/>
                Town: {{ad.town}}<br/>
                Brand: {{ad.brand}}<br/>
                Model: {{ad.model}}<br/>
                Type: {{ad.type}}<br/>
                Auth: {{ad.auth}}<br/>
                Condition: {{ad.condition}}<br/>
                Trade: {{ad.trade}}<br/>
                Price: {{ad.price}}</p>


        </div>
        <uib-pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="ads.length"  items-per-page="numPerPage" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true"></uib-pagination>
        <p>{{ads.length}} and {{maxSize}} and {{currentPage}}</p>

    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>


</body>


</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("ngTest",['ui.bootstrap'])
```

**script.js**

```
    (function(){
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("ngTest")
        .controller("testCtrl",function($scope, $http){

           $http.get('test.json').then(function(result){

                $scope.filteredAds = [];
                   $scope.currentPage = 1;
                   $scope.numPerPage = 2;
                   $scope.maxSize = 5;



                  $scope.ads = result.data;
               $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
                   var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
                       , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

                  $scope.filteredAds = $scope.ads.slice(begin,end);
               });





               $scope.typeIncludes = [];
               $scope.includeType = function(type) {
                   var i = $.inArray(type, $scope.typeIncludes);
                   if (i > -1) {
                       $scope.typeIncludes.splice(i, 1);
                   } else {
                       $scope.typeIncludes.push(type);
                   }
               }

               $scope.typeFilter = function(ads) {
                   if ($scope.typeIncludes.length > 0) {
                       if ($.inArray(ads.type, $scope.typeIncludes) < 0)
                           return;
                   }

                       return ads;

               }

               $scope.districtIncludes = [];
               $scope.includeDistrict = function(district) {
                   var i = $.inArray(district, $scope.districtIncludes);
                   if (i > -1) {
                       $scope.districtIncludes.splice(i, 1);
                   } else {
                       $scope.districtIncludes.push(district);
                   }
               }

               $scope.districtFilter = function(ads) {
                   if ($scope.districtIncludes.length > 0) {
                       if ($.inArray(ads.district, $scope.districtIncludes) < 0)
                           return;
                   }

                   return ads;
               }




           });


        });

})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RV6pQYMTzETZGNKdAFGb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a question of style, but I wouldn't use filters for eliminating data from a collection. I tend to process the data in the controller, or in a service, before serving it to the view.

Moreover, in my experience, it is not good to assign a new value to a watched collection: the original reference is lost and AngularJS is confused.
Therefore, I rather manipulate the original array, to insert or remove items from it.